# Open Android App from SMS

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I am building an Ionic 2/3 application utilizing Ionic's [deep linking plugin](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/deeplinks/). The complete solution utilizes SMS to send an alert to the device. The SMS message contains a deep link url, like myapp://0123456789acrazylongid. The native Andorid SMS application reads part of the content as a phone number. My understanding of how this should work is that by specifying the schema in the config.xml as seen here.

```
<plugin name="ionic-plugin-deeplinks" spec="^1.0.15">
    <variable name="URL_SCHEME" value="myapp" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_SCHEME" value="https" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_HOST" value="app.mysample.com" />
</plugin>
```

The application should be registered with the device and then all applications running on the device would know about myapp://. This does appear to work as I expect with iOS, just not Android. I have reviewed all of the documentation available from Google - [Handling Android App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html).

I would appreciate any guidance possible.

Comment: if you find a solution please post it here, as i'm struck with a similar issue